# Script to allow traffic to ports 53,22,443,80 and drop others, BUT I can't run apt-get update

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking

I'm writing a script to drop all inputs and outputs traffic except traffic on those ports (53,22,80,443) but I can't apt-get update.

```
#!/bin/sh    
# Flushing all rules
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow incoming SSH
iptables -A INPUT -i ens33 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o ens33 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing SSH
iptables -A OUTPUT -o ens33 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i ens33 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming HTTP
iptables -A INPUT -i ens33 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o ens33 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing HTTP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o ens33 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i ens33 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming HTTPS
iptables -A INPUT -i ens33 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o ens33 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing HTTPS
iptables -A OUTPUT -o ens33 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i ens33 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming DNS
iptables -A INPUT -i ens33 -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o ens33 -p tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: You didn't allow ICMP!

Answer (score 2):

Filtering output (local originated) packets isn't a common practice, better don't do it if you don't sure what you're doing exactly.

To allow the outgoing dns (required by dns resolving) you should accept new state packets to 53 port in OUTPUT chain.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Also in your case you need some another rules (and corresponded mirred rules in OUTPUT chain):

- Allow the local connections (`iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`)
- Allow RELATED connections (add `RELATED` into `--state` matches), it also allow replied ICMP packets.
- Allow ICMP.

Also check the ipv6 rule set (use `iptables6` command).

Related document: the iptables tutorial.